# Is there a way to reroute around the Frequent Sites page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I am attempting to make my companies Sharepoint site a little more user friendly and easier to navigate.  Our users complain about the Frequent Sites page regularly and i would like to reroute users upon sign in, to our Home page.  I'm hoping someone here can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By "frequent sites page", I assume you mean the sharepoint page, located at "_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx"? If so, how are your users getting there to begin with? The system doesn't take users to that site automatically. Perhaps their browser has it set as the home page? If so, the simple solution is to set whatever page you want as the home page in their browser settings.

Though, another part of that answer might be training for the users as to the purpose and functionality of the the listing of frequent sites. It's difficult to imagine a knowledgeable user complaining about it, as this is a common element that shows up in windows and other sites. On the start menu, we have "most used", and other apps will also surface content or organize content based on usage.

Comment: Yes, that is the site I am referring to.  When my users sign into Office.com and select the SharePoint app, it routes to this page.  I would like it to route to the home page i have selected but i havent been able to figure this out.  I am new to SharePoint configuration and am just figuring it out as i go along.  I work for a home improvement company and our users are not very savvy.

Comment: If they click on the link to go to the SharePoint Page, yes, it takes them to the SharePoint page.  Again, options include setting the home page of their browser to automatically go to the desired site. Or, communications to users could be to tell them to go to "https://somecompany.sharepoint.com", instead of portal.office.com

Comment: I'm going to take this as a 'no' that there is no way to get around that page other than training. lol  I really do appreciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: You selected the sharepoint-enterprise and sharepoint-foundation categories, but then in your comment mentioned Office.com. Is this for SharePoint Online? (sharepoint-enterprise and sharepoint-foundation) imply on-prem)

Answer (score 0):

I know what you mean. After users click "SharePoint" app, they will go to the _layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx page. And you want to make this default page as your homepage.

This is by design and can cannot be routed to another page.

The only workaround I can imagine is that let your users save your homepage(SitePages/Home.aspx) as a bookmark. Then they can directly click the bookmark to signing into your homepage without signing into Office.com.